# Convert a string to date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following string and I want to convert it to Date

`'20220722T141444Z'`

In **C#** I converted it by telerik's **DateParser** library.

Is there a way to convert it in **JavaScript** as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many questions on parsing timestamps. In this case, you can just get the parts as two digit pairs then use that to call the *Date* constructor.

Since the timestamp has a trailing "Z", likely it should be parsed as UTC so:

```js
let ts = '20220722T141444Z'
let [C,Y,M,D,H,m,s] = ts.match(/\d\d/g) || [];
let date = new Date(Date.UTC(C+Y, M-1, D, H, m, s));

console.log(date.toISOString());
```

There are many other ways to approach the problem, such as modifying the values to create a supported format such as `2022-07-22T14:14:44Z', however it's more efficient to give the parts directly to the *Date* constructor than to build a string then have the built–in parser parse it.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way in javascript but i think it wont work with this format

change the format like this and try

```js
new Date('20220722T141444Z')
Invalid Date
new Date('20220722')
Invalid Date
new Date('2022 07 22')
Fri Jul 22 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: Suggesting parsing to an unsupported format is not a good idea. Far better to get the parts and call the *Date* constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Because `new Date(string)` returns an `Invalid Date` I'd do it like that and use [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
function date(a) {
    return `${a.slice(6, 8)}.${a.slice(4, 6)}.${a.slice(0, 4)}`;
}

console.log(date("20220722T141444Z"));
// output: 22.07.2022
```

Comment: Consider posting your code as a runnable snippet. It doesn't produce a *Date* instance, it creates a timestamp in a format like "22.07.2022".

Answer (score 0):

The [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library will convert this format by default by just calling the below. This will however involve the addition of the new library into your project.

`moment('20220722T141444Z') // "Fri Jul 22 2022 15:14:44 GMT+0100"`

To use vanilla JS only, you'd have to parse the date yourself as mentioned in several other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the input string to an ISO date, this can then be parsed by the Date constructor.

This should work if the input has a UTC offset other than 'Z', for example '+05:30'.

```js
let input = '20220722T141444Z';

function toIso(input) { 
    return [...input].reduce((s, chr, idx) => s + ([4,6,11,13].includes(idx) ? (idx < 11) ? '-': ':': '') + chr , '');
}

console.log('Input (ISO):', toIso(input))
console.log('Date.toISOString():', new Date(toIso(input)).toISOString())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```